# How do I locate and move content in my drupal theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-themes

I am making design changes to a site for a client that was created with drupal. Looks like a drupal 7 site.

I have located the theme files. The page.tpl.php has an include of page-ajaz.tpl.php

That file has the following code

```
    <div <?php print drupal_attributes($attr) ?>>

  <?php if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') { ?>
    <title <?php print drupal_attributes($attr) ?>><?php print $head_title ?></title>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php print $breadcrumb ?>

  <h1 class='page-title'>
    <?php print $title; ?>
  </h1>

  <?php if ($tabs) { ?>
    <div class="tabs"><?php print $tabs ?></div>
    <?php if ($tabs2) { ?>
      <div class="tabs second"><?php print $tabs2 ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>

  <div class="page-content">
    <?php if ($messages) { ?>
      <div class="messages"><?php print $messages ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php
      print $help;      
      print $content;
      print $feed_icons;
    ?>
  </div>

</div>

<?php 
if (in_array('page-ajax', $variables['template_files'])) {
  $settings_js = drupal_add_js();
  unset($settings_js['core']);
  unset($settings_js['module']);
  unset($settings_js['theme']);
  print drupal_get_js('header', $settings_js);
}
?>
```

What the client would like is for a form that is located with in the $content var to be moved an placed above the H1 page-title.

It looks like the developer used something called views-exposed-form.tpl.php. My guess is that this is a template for a module they are using called better_exposed_filters.

What I am having trouble figuring out is how to move form that is generated by this module so that it appears above the title H1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  to  find somthing like "views exposed filter" block  in blocks administration page. 
Move this block from content region to another. Check form changed location or not.
If  yes move block to region in preferred location (maybe yo  have to  define this region).